# ROLI JUCE Android CMake Error, Generated blank demo app fails to compile in Android Studio

Tags: android, c++, makefile, cmake, juce

Having downloaded the Projucer I generated a blank application, I exported it to Android (in debug mode) and opened it in Android studio. 
After fixing errors to do with the versions of the SDK and NDK (I updated the references to build with the most recent version) the code fails to build at the CMake stage with the below error output:

```
Build command failed.
Error while executing process /Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/cmake/3.6.4111459/bin/cmake with arguments {--build /Users/user/Documents/Blank/Builds/Android/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug_Debug/x86 --target juce_jni}
[1/16] Building C object CMakeFiles/cpufeatures.dir/Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/android/cpufeatures/cpu-features.c.o
[2/16] Linking C static library libcpufeatures.a
[3/16] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/juce_jni.dir/Users/user/Documents/Blank/JuceLibraryCode/include_juce_audio_basics.cpp.o
[4/16] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/juce_jni.dir/Users/user/Documents/Blank/JuceLibraryCode/include_juce_audio_devices.cpp.o
[5/16] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/juce_jni.dir/Users/user/Documents/Blank/JuceLibraryCode/include_juce_audio_formats.cpp.o
[6/16] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/juce_jni.dir/Users/user/Documents/Blank/JuceLibraryCode/include_juce_audio_processors.cpp.o
[7/16] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/juce_jni.dir/Users/user/Documents/Blank/JuceLibraryCode/include_juce_core.cpp.o
[8/16] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/juce_jni.dir/Users/user/Documents/Blank/JuceLibraryCode/include_juce_cryptography.cpp.o
[9/16] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/juce_jni.dir/Users/user/Documents/Blank/JuceLibraryCode/include_juce_data_structures.cpp.o
[10/16] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/juce_jni.dir/Users/user/Documents/Blank/JuceLibraryCode/include_juce_events.cpp.o
[11/16] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/juce_jni.dir/Users/user/Documents/Blank/JuceLibraryCode/include_juce_graphics.cpp.o
[12/16] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/juce_jni.dir/Users/user/Documents/Blank/JuceLibraryCode/include_juce_gui_basics.cpp.o
[13/16] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/juce_jni.dir/Users/user/Documents/Blank/JuceLibraryCode/include_juce_gui_extra.cpp.o
[14/16] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/juce_jni.dir/Users/user/Documents/Blank/JuceLibraryCode/include_juce_opengl.cpp.o
FAILED: /Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang++  --target=i686-none-linux-android28 --gcc-toolchain=/Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64  -DDEBUG=1 -DJUCER_ANDROIDSTUDIO_7F0E4A25=1 -DJUCE_ANDROID=1 -DJUCE_ANDROID_ACTIVITY_CLASSNAME=com_yourcompany_blank_Blank -DJUCE_ANDROID_ACTIVITY_CLASSPATH=\"com/yourcompany/blank/Blank\" -DJUCE_ANDROID_API_VERSION=10 -DJUCE_ANDROID_SHARING_CONTENT_PROVIDER_CLASSNAME=com_yourcompany_blank_SharingContentProvider -DJUCE_ANDROID_SHARING_CONTENT_PROVIDER_CLASSPATH=\"com/yourcompany/blank/SharingContentProvider\" -DJUCE_APP_VERSION=1.0.0 -DJUCE_APP_VERSION_HEX=0x10000 -DJUCE_PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS=1 -D_DEBUG=1 -Djuce_jni_EXPORTS -I../../../../../../../JuceLibraryCode -I/Users/user/Downloads/JUCE/modules -I/Users/molly/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/android/cpufeatures --sysroot /Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/sysroot -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11 -fexceptions -frtti -fsigned-char -std=c++14 -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info -O0 -fPIC -MD -MT CMakeFiles/juce_jni.dir/Users/user/Documents/Blank/JuceLibraryCode/include_juce_opengl.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/juce_jni.dir/Users/user/Documents/Blank/JuceLibraryCode/include_juce_opengl.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/juce_jni.dir/Users/user/Documents/Blank/JuceLibraryCode/include_juce_opengl.cpp.o -c /Users/user/Documents/Blank/JuceLibraryCode/include_juce_opengl.cpp
In file included from /Users/user/Documents/Blank/JuceLibraryCode/include_juce_opengl.cpp:9:
/Users/user/Downloads/JUCE/modules/juce_opengl/juce_opengl.cpp:118:26: error: no member named 'glDrawBuffer' in the global namespace; did you mean simply 'glDrawBuffer'?
 JUCE_GL_BASE_FUNCTIONS (JUCE_DECLARE_GL_FUNCTION)
 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/user/Downloads/JUCE/modules/juce_opengl/native/juce_OpenGLExtensions.h:69:5: note: expanded from macro 'JUCE_GL_BASE_FUNCTIONS'
    USE_FUNCTION (glDrawBuffer,            void, (GLsizei p1, const GLenum* p2), (p1, p2))
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/user/Downloads/JUCE/modules/juce_opengl/juce_opengl.cpp:116:72: note: expanded from macro 'JUCE_DECLARE_GL_FUNCTION'
    returnType OpenGLExtensionFunctions::name params noexcept { return ::name callparams; }
                                                                       ^~
/Users/user/Downloads/JUCE/modules/juce_opengl/juce_opengl.cpp:118:2: note: 'glDrawBuffer' declared here
 JUCE_GL_BASE_FUNCTIONS (JUCE_DECLARE_GL_FUNCTION)
 ^
/Users/user/Downloads/JUCE/modules/juce_opengl/native/juce_OpenGLExtensions.h:69:19: note: expanded from macro 'JUCE_GL_BASE_FUNCTIONS'
    USE_FUNCTION (glDrawBuffer,            void, (GLsizei p1, const GLenum* p2), (p1, p2))
                  ^
1 error generated.
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

I have tried reinstalling the Projucer, running different versions of Android Studio and generating different Demo projects but they all fail at the same point. When generating an Xcode file on the same computer (macOS) and same Projucer download the code does compile and run on an emulated iOS.

Am I missing some library or is there an incorrect file path somewhere?

The file that throws the error is from their own library so I am unsure what could be causing the issue, any help would be much appreciated!

The error occurs specifically on the line USE_FUCNTION(glDrawBuffer ...) as I have tried moving this line of code in the library file and the error moves with it (it is at the end of a code block so I wanted to see if it was that code block that was failing but it seems to be specifically that line)

Comment: Have you tried to ask on their forum? They are usually reponding very fast.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher Yes, I have posted on their forum and linked it to this post, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Set the “Minimum SDK Version” in the Android exporter to something like 24, rather than the default of 10.

The current default is a little low and will be bumped up to 28 in the next JUCE release.